# How to cache the image in swift using SDWebImage?

Tags: swift, caching, sdwebimage

I am fetching the image from firebase storage and want to cache it using `SDWebImage`, but in my `ViewController` it gets keep on downloaded. Please guide me how to cache the images

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! demoCell
        cell.textDemo.text = images[indexPath.row]

        var images_list = [String]()
        images_list.append(images[indexPath.row])
        images_list.append(images[indexPath.row] + "1")
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
        var imagesarray = [URL]()


        for x in images_list{
        let storageRef = storage.child("images/\(x).jpg")
        storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            else if let downloadURL = url?.absoluteString{
                cell.imageDemo.image = SDImageCache.shared().imageFromCache(forKey: downloadURL)
                print("Image Cached")
            }
            else{
                cell.imageDemo.sd_setImage(with: url!, completed: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
    }
```

Comment: SDWebimage already done this thing by default, no need to do SDImageCache like this.

Comment: I did answer this question previously. It get cached when you do `sd_setImage` and if the URL is same next time, the image is fetched from cache. Also the way you are doing stuff on `cellForRowAt` can be made much more efficient by downloading the `dataSource` outside of table and then only using the url

Comment: I also did the same as you suggested, but when i do that, the image gets downloaded each time i Scroll the table view. Now i will post an answer please do review and help me for how to store it offline when user doesn't have internet connection

Comment: If your problem is continue , you can use KingFisher

Comment: Yeah will try it for sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than writing :

```
cell.imageDemo.image = SDImageCache.shared().imageFromCache(forKey: downloadURL)
```

Try this :

```
cell.imageDemo.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: downloadURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Your Default Image"))
```

`SDWebImage` will handle the caching part here.

Comment: Thanks for the help bro, I will post an answer please do review it and help me how to store the image offline in as disk cache

Answer (score 3):

This was my solution to the issue

```
var value : Any?
var vc = ViewController()
var images = [String]()
var downloads_array = [URL]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getImageNames()
    downloadImages()

}

func downloadImages(){
    let storage = Storage.storage().reference()

    for x in images{
    let storageRef = storage.child("images/\(x).jpg")
        storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            else{
                self.downloads_array.append(url!)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

func getImageNames(){
    images = vc.images
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return downloads_array.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! demoCell
    cell.textDemo.text = images[indexPath.row]

    if let downloadURL = SDImageCache.shared().imageFromCache(forKey: downloads_array[indexPath.row].absoluteString){
        cell.imageDemo.image = downloadURL
    }
    else{
        cell.imageDemo.sd_setImage(with: downloads_array[indexPath.row], completed: nil)
    }



    return cell
}
```